# cherrypy throws Exception which causes Internal Server Error when using blocking gevent calls

Tags: cherrypy, gevent

I'm using gevent wsgi to run a cherrypy application, and doing some blocking gevent calls in the request handers. The blocking calls work as expected successfully parallelizing the usage of some blocking resources ( pipes to other processes ) if I make single requests. The Problem arises when I fire multiple requests, then cherrypy returns an Internal Server Error throwing this Exception:

```
[23/Mar/2012:17:50:35]  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpwsgi.py", line 170, in trap
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpwsgi.py", line 97, in __call__
return self.nextapp(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpwsgi.py", line 385, in tail
return self.response_class(environ, start_response, self.cpapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpwsgi.py", line 232, in __init__
outstatus = r.output_status
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'output_status'
```

I reduced the problem to the core, and the following simple application reproduces the problem every time:

```
import cherrypy
import gevent
from gevent import wsgi

class BugServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
      gevent.sleep(2)
      return 'dummy foo'

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = cherrypy.tree.mount(BugServer(), '/')
        wsgi.WSGIServer(('', 27726), app).serve_forever()
```

To test it I used the following script which fires three requests simultaneously:

```
import httplib
import threading

def make_req(host):
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
        conn.request("GET", "/")
        return conn.getresponse()

threads = []
for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=make_req, args=('192.168.128.7:27726',), kwargs={})
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I'm not sure if I have to dig into the cherrypy or the gevent (wsgi) library to find the bug. Setting spawn=None to the wsgi server would defy the purpose of using greenlets for blocking resource calls in the requests, and doesn't work anyway.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Cherrypy uses threading.local for its request\response objects (if it is supported by your Python version). This object can be patched to use gevent local storage using gevent.monkey.patch_all. Just use:

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
patch_all()
```

before any of the imports (you can then even use the normal "time" function instead of gevent.time). This fixed it here.

Answer (score 2):

CherryPy uses threadlocals extensively, and therefore isn't designed for use with event loops or other approaches which handle multiple requests with the same thread. It might appear to work for a while if your tests make calls synchronously, but as soon as you try multiple simultaneous requests (that arrive faster than the handlers can return responses) you will encounter this sort of error.

It should be possible to replace `cherrypy.serving` with some sort of context object that is designed for greenlets or other parallelisms, but to date nobody has taken the time to experiment.

Comment: ah, i see. and there is no way to make the server always process requests synchronously ? Because the whole parallelisation is  already implemented below request level. Anyways, thanks for the tip, and i'll try and look into cheryrpy.serving. If i don't find any switch to do that i'll consider using another web framework or none at all actually, i only need it for a very specialized kind of request that uses much processing power.